# Intercepting spawned URL requests from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I'm trying to cache specified web pages to disk by NSURLProtocol,now I can only get the first URL request, but the UIWebView spawns further URL requests for loading graphics. So how can I Intercept all the requests spawned by UIWebView from the first URL?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Implement delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

every time your webview loads url it will first call this method.

Comment: Thank you ,but I found the shouldStartLoadWithRequest catch only first request of the UIWebView, the other requests such as image requests, js requests do not call this function.